# Умножить два вектора и получить матрицу

Tags: python, numpy

У меня есть два массива:

```
arr1 = np.array([1, 2])
arr2 = np.array([3, 4, 5])
```

Kак мне их умножить и получить матрицу:

```
[
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 8, 10]
]
```

Я использую следующее решение:

```
np.dot(arr1.reshape((2, 1)), arr2.reshape((1, 3)))
```

Но на мой взгляд это не удобно. Какие существуют более удобные решения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
res = np.multiply.outer(arr1, arr2)
```

результат:

```
In [110]: res
Out[110]: 
array([[ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  8, 10]])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
res = (np.array([arr2,]*2).T*arr1).T
```

```
array([[ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  8, 10]])
```